# Replacing multiple values in an array in hive

Tags: hive, hql

I have a column which contains languages which is displayed in full, I need to change that and send the ISO format.

`SELECT id, get_json_object(json_data, '$.languages') AS language from someTable`

data in json_data column:

```
 {
   languages : ['English','French','Japanese']
 }
```

I want to understand how to write the hql query so that I can extract language and replace each language with the iso code.

current result

| Id | Language |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['English,'French','Japanese'] |
| 2 | ['English,'Kannada','Japanese','Hindi'] |

Expected result

| Id | Language |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['en,'fr','jp'] |
| 2 | ['en,'kn','jp','hn'] |

I am aware I can use the `replace_regex` function but since there are could be many languages, it could result in a lot of nesting of replace_regex, any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the column is of type `array<string>` you can use [LATERAL VIEW explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+lateralview) to pivot the array of strings into a `string` column. Once pivoted you can either join with a table to convert the full string into the iso format or use a `case statement` if number of languages is not big.

After languages are mapped into the iso code, you can use `collect_list(col)` to convert the list back to `array<string>`

So something like that may work

```
select id,collect_list(
case 
when language = 'English' then 'en'
...
end) as language_iso_codes
from tab lateral view explode(languages) lang as language
group by id
```

If it is a JSON string rather than the `array<string>` then you  can use regex to convert the JSON into comma-separated list and then use `split(col,',')` to get the `array<string>` followed by `explode` as above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following in order of preference for such problems:

1. Create a dictionary table in Hive with all the languages and their ISO code, then join with this table in your query.
2. If all language names for your array correspond to what Java returns with its `Locale.getLanguage()`, then it also makes sense to [create UDF](https://www.runtastic.com/blog/en/how-to-write-user-defined-functions-for-hive/):

```
package org.yours.udf;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyLangUDF extends UDF {
    public List<String> evaluate(List<String> languages) {
      Map<String, String> map = 
        Arrays
        .asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales())
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(lc -> lc.getDisplayName().toLowerCase(), lc -> lc.getLanguage().toLowerCase()));
        
      List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String a: languages) {
        res.add(map.get(a.toLowerCase()));
      }
      return res;
    }
  }

}
```

This UDF and its `evaluate` function will accept and return `List` of language names.